# Can you use Wish to allow yourself to cast Wish without risks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

In D&D, [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) is an extremely powerfull spell, but it also comes with its risks:

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell. This damage can't be reduced or prevented in any way. In addition, your Strength drops to 3, if it isn't 3 or lower already, for 2d4 days. For each of those days that you spend resting and doing nothing more than light activity, your remaining recovery time decreases by 2 days. Finally, there is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast *wish* ever again if you suffer this stress.

This consequence ensures that the players can't exploit this spell, at least, not too much. But, since the spell *wish* basically allows us to do almost anything, is there any reason that prevents a player from doing something like this:

> I wish to be able to cast *wish*, without ever suffering stress from it.

Now, apart from rule 0, is there any written rule preventing this? Or is it technically allowed?

Comment: Just wondering. Does the player's character *know* of the consequences of casting a Wish spell? If not, as how you stated it, isn't it a bit "metagamey"?

Comment: @jcordova I think they would, I think that most spell caster knows of the consequences, and risks of the spells they casts, before casting them.

Comment: ♦ Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, [not posting small or incomplete answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534). Please only use answer posts to submit answers on the site. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The consequences of the wording of a wish are, as you note, entirely at the whim of a DM. No one can answer how any particular DM will rule, so keep in mind that any answer is on shaky ground, subjectively.

A DM could rule that you are granted this ability by virtue of being unable to cast Wish for anything but spell duplication, for example.

However, the wish you specify will have to be cast before it takes effect, and you could almost certainly undergo stress from it, with the potential of it being permanent.

Comment: Limiting wish to spell duplication is the exact outcome that I'd expect, because that's what has been wished for.

Answer (score 22):

Let's split this question in two:

## Can I wish "to be able to cast Wish, without ever suffering Stress from it."?

**Yes**, you can wish anything you like.

## Will this wish be granted? If yes, how will this wish be granted?

That's **up to the DM**. The main point here is that this is not even about Rule 0, this is explicitly how Wish itself is written. I.e., this is the RAW answer.

> State your wish to the DM as precisely as possible. The DM has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance, the greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong. This spell might simply fail, the effect you desire might only be partly achieved, or you might suffer some unforeseen consequence as a result of how you worded the wish.

As other answers mentioned, possible outcomes (Note: all of these are backed up by the above rule) are:

- It doesn't work at all.
- You can only cast Wish to duplicate other spells, therefore still being able to cast Wish and never suffering stress from it. (Note: this outcome can be prevented with a different wording, like "I wish I can cast Wish, **without any restriction** and without ever suffering stress from it".)
- I disagree that you could lose the ability to cast Wish, since your Wish explicitly states that you want to be able to cast it.
- Even if you can cast Wish without stress, you would still take the damage from it, since it explicitly states that the damage can't be reduced or prevented by *any* means. This last point makes the RAI a little awkward, since you can prevent the stress, but can't prevent the damage from the stress.

Comment: You can cast wish only to wish that you suffer no ill-effects from the wish spell.

Comment: Alternative outcome: You wish is granted, and the casting of that particular wish is free from restrictions or stress consequences. Nothing else happens. All future wish spells are cast normally.

Comment: You could still lose the ability.  If the wish spell fails (always a possibility with write-your-own wishes) and then you suffered lost-Wish stress....

Answer (score 13):

Well you would suffer the stress from casting it at least once, so the damage could be done.

Consider also:

> You might be able to achieve something beyond the scope of the above examples. State your wish to the DM as precisely as possible. The DM has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance, the greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong. This spell might simply fail, the effect you desire might only be partly achieved, or you might suffer some unforeseen consequence as a result of how you worded the wish.

Your DM may find that your request is beyond what can be achieved and outright refuse it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer would appear to be in the description

> This damage can't be reduced or prevented in any way

Though arguably that might just apply to the "1d10 necrotic damage". If I were the GM though, I'd think about extending it to applying to the rest too.

Comment: The term "damage" indeed refers only to damage, not to things that are not damage. This doesn't really clearly answer the rest of the question.

Answer (score -6):

Like with a Genie or Trickster, the results of a *Wish* are entirely up to the DM via example below:

DM response:

> You now have a magical fishing rod, that’s indestructible, grants you tool proficiency: Fishing Rod, with expertise in “Fishing”, that has a lure with the word “wish” on it which is enchanted with *True Strike*.

DM makes a secret *Zocchihedron* roll:

> As you revel in your new founded ability to *cast* Wish without risk, you now feel a strong weakness come upon you as if your strength has been drained from you.

You can no longer cast that particular 9th level spell again.

Comment: What does the second example mean? Does it imply that you cannot actually cast it anymore?

Comment: As per 3rd part of spell, can not cast Wish again, yes.

Comment: My +1 was for the first half, and even better there is good mythical support for it. However, assuming DM wants to allow it, I think doing what you suggest with the fishing rod would still be a good idea anyway. Imagine if the player could cast the wish spell without risk, but every time they did so they had to "cast" the "wish" lure to enable them to cast the wish spell? That would be awesome in a hilarious way, and it would still provide drawbacks (what if the rod breaks? what if OP forgets to bring it? etc.) and would make protecting and safeguarding that fragile tool paramount.