# Can I return my ability to cast Wish by using the Glyph of Warding spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish, traps

The description of [*Wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) in the *Player's Handbook* says that if you use it to do anything other than duplicating another spell, you suffer stress, one of the results of which is:

> There is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast *wish* ever
>   again.

The description of [*Glyph of Warding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) says that I can put any spell into the glyph, even a 9th-level spell.

What will happen if a wizard creates a [*Glyph of Warding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) using a 9th-level spell slot, and inscribes the [*Wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell, with the words being: "I wish to get back my ability to cast *Wish*"?

Note that the wizard does this *before* they lose the ability to cast [*Wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish).

Will this work as I think it should?

Comment: You mean you are creating a Glyph with this wish, *before* losing your ability to cast *wish* and then you'd plan on triggering it if you lose the ability to get your *wishing* ability back? Is this correct?

Comment: How are you creating a 9th level *glyph of warding*? You would need two 9th level slots or higher slots (read: it's not easy). Related: [Is there a way to store 9th-level spells in a Glyph of Warding or similar method?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141924/41726)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose yes, the plan was: to create a glyph which contains the wish with certain description, that will give me back ability to cast wish again if my character loses it by any circumstances

Comment: Related: [Can you use Wish to allow yourself to cast Wish without risks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120625/can-you-use-wish-to-allow-yourself-to-cast-wish-without-risks)

Answer (score 20):

### **First Answer: Not Easily.**

So, I'll assume you're talking about prepping a *wish*-glyph prior to losing the ability to cast wish.  At that point, you should be able to cast a 9th-level Glyph of Warding, and you should be able to cast a 9th-level Wish.  Unfortunately for you, it's not that easy, as you have to cast them at the same time, and the only way to get a character with two 9th-level spell slots is via Boon of High Magic... with means that either your DM is being exceedingly generous with you, or you're in a campaign that hit 20 some time ago, and have been collecting Boons.  That's not normal state, even among casters who *can* cast Wish.

Now, it's still doable, even without extraordinary Boons.  You could write the Glyph of Warding onto a spell scroll, and then use that for the combined casting.  It's rather more time-consuming and expensive, but it would be doable.

Of course, you're using Wish.  You *could* just Wish for a Wish-glyph to cast this particular Wish on you, and save yourself the extra slot issue.  That... has issues we'll cover a little later on.

### **Second Answer: Not Safely**

Even after you get over that hump, though, you're still dealing with *Wish*... and you're doing so on an entirely custom effect.  The text for wishing with custom effects is as follows:

> You might be able to achieve something beyond the scope of the above
>   examples. State your wish to the GM as precisely as possible. The GM
>   has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance; the
>   greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes
>   wrong. This spell might simply fail, the effect you desire might only
>   be partly achieved, or you might suffer some unforeseen consequence as
>   a result of how you worded the wish. For example, wishing that a
>   villain were dead might propel you forward in time to a period when
>   that villain is no longer alive, effectively removing you from the
>   game. Similarly, wishing for a legendary magic item or artifact might
>   instantly transport you to the presence of the item’s current owner.

I don't know about you, but that doesn't fill me with confidence that This Will Definitely Work... and phrases like "unable to cast *wish* ever again" (as contrasted to something like "lose the ability to cast *wish*") don't help any.

Finally, it's worth noting that casting wish into the Glyph in this way is exactly the sort of wish-casting that might lose you your ability to cast wish.

So... you could try to set up this contingency, yes.  Assuming you haven't been granted the Boon of High Magic, it will be somewhat costly and/or time consuming (scribing 9th-level scrolls ain't cheap), there's a 1-in-3 chance that you'll have to trigger your contingency in the setup process, and there's a good chance (with a lot of DM fiat) that it'll fail utterly or that something else goes wrong.  Still... it *might* work.

As for Wishing for a Wish-glyph, that's just compounding your issues here.  It means two nonstandard Wish effects for the DM to adjudicate instead of just one.  There's also that bit about "the greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong".  Asking your Wish spell to shoulder the load of a Glyph in addition to its other burdens seems like it would make that Wish at least a bit "greater" for those purposes.  Given how much this plan is digging into its shenanigans budget already, it's probably better to just pony up for the scroll.

Comment: Related on your first point: [Is there a way to store 9th-level spells in a Glyph of Warding or similar method?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141924/41726)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose fair point.  I tend to ignore Boons for questions from the player perspective, but they *are* officially a part of the game.  Adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Might as well wish for there to be a glyph which has stored the "I wish to get back my ability to cast Wish" wish.

Comment: @Ruse An interesting idea.  I've modified my answer to address it.

Answer (score 12):

## It doesn't matter if this particular sequence works or not because the GM doesn't have to grant your wish

The [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell contains the following clause :

> The GM has great latitude in ruling what occurs [...]. This spell might simply fail

If the GM allows this sequence to play out as you described, then it will still only depend on their ruling of the *Wish* whether you get it back or not.

If the GM wants to take away your ability to wish, they can and there's nothing you can do to force them to give it back.

Comment: The DM of course can do what he want. I just want to clarify if it is possible by the rules.

Comment: @anonymousbadger That the GM determines the results of *wish* **is** the rules

Comment: @AnonymousBadger I get that, but I'm saying it doesn't matter because in the end it only depends on the GM's desire to grant you *Wish* back or not. I'll try to make it clearer

Comment: Or use granting the wish in a negative way, like the examples given in the spell. Wish to to be able to cast wish again, and  the wish sends you back in time to before the catastrophe when wish did not have a penalty. You essentially disappear from the game, until you cast wish again to come back at which point you can't cast wish again.

Answer (score -2):

## Adventurers' League claims it will work - some of the time

### General rule on *Wish* restoring *Wish*

According to Adventurers' League rules, *Wish*ing back the ability to cast *Wish* is a valid use of the spell, and is, in fact, the only way to undo the loss of the spell. [Adventurers' League FAQ](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv9.pdf) current as of this answer (under the heading for *Wish*) confirm that the fourth bullet point of *Wish* works on the stress roll itself.

The caster whose ability is being restored gets to reroll the 33% chance of stress, and has a 67% chance of now being able to cast *Wish* again. Unfortunately, the caster doing the restoring must also make the roll, and may lose the ability.

Therefore, there is a 4 in 9 chance that both casters are now fine, a 1 in 9 chance that they are both unhappy, and a 4 in 9 chance that nothing really changed (one can and one can't).

Note that the second *Wish* must be cast immediately, and that this is of course subject to DM rulings in non-AL games.

### Restoring *Wish* with a *Glyph*

In your case, you would be both casters. Like readying a spell, casting a spell into a *Glyph* is actually casting it - you'd have to make the roll there and then. You'd have a 1 in 9 chance of losing *Wish* forever with this gambit for no gain - but a 2 in 3 chance of having a 67% chance of saving yourself later if you ever fail that stress roll later.

**Credit to [Joeorbob](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/57467/joeorbob) for finding the reference in the current AL FAQ for me.**

Comment: I don't see how your Glyph numbers come around. I suppose the 1 in 9 chance is because that's the odds of you losing Wish when casting the Wish and the Glyph failing to restore it, but then where does the 2 in 3 come? There seems to be a situation missing that happens in the remaining 2 in 9 situations?

Comment: @Erik You fail initial rol, but instantly restore ability to cast Wish from a glyph you just cast.

Comment: Where does the "reroll the 33% chance of stress" (instead of just getting your ability back) part come from?  Is that basically a GM fiat decision handed down from whoever has the GM fiat powers in AL?

Comment: This seems like an interesting ruling, especially if it's indeed official AL policy, but right now there's nothing but your vague recollection backing this up. I'd definitely upvote this answer, and encourage others to do so, if you could dig up that missing reference.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The closest I can see is looking in this (most current as of this comment)  [FAQ](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv9.pdf), which says "Losing the ability to cast _wish_ in the
future can be undone only by _wishing_ for a reroll (as
detailed in the spells description)". To me this implies it uses _wish_'s "reroll something from the last turn" effect, which I would expect to be allowed in AL. However, based on _wish_'s description, it only seems available within one round of the previous _wish_.